# Give a example to show that there not necessarily exist uniformly bounded linear funtionals $\{f_j\}$ such that $f_j(x_k)=\delta_{jk}$.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, dual-spaces, schauder-basis

> Suppose $E$ is a normed linear space, $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$  is linearly independent and $\|x_k\|=1, k=1,2,\cdots$. Give a example to show that there not necessarily exist uniformly bounded linear funtionals $\{f_j\}$ such that  $f_j(x_k)=\delta_{jk},\ j,k\geq 1$.

I know there are already many posts on MSE discussing about dual basis of infinite dimensional space and the finite case of my question. But I have not founded the answer of my question. Appreciate any help or hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider an infinite dimensional Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}.$ Let  $$ x_1=e_1,\qquad x_n=\cos (n^{-1})\,e_1+\sin(n^{-1})\,e_n, \quad n\ge 2$$
The elements  $x_n$ are
linearly idependent, $\|x_n\|=1$  and $x_n\to x_1.$  If $f_1$ existed then
$$0=\lim_n f_1(x_n)=f_1(x_1)=1,$$ which would give a contradiction.

In the example the sequence $x_n$ does not satisfy $$\qquad \qquad\|x_n-x_m\|\ge \delta>0,\qquad  n\neq m, \qquad\qquad\qquad(1) $$
However, it is possible to construct a counterexample satisfying $(1).$

Indeed, let $$x_1=\sum_{k=1}^\infty {1\over \sqrt{k(k+1)}}e_k,\qquad x_n=e_{n-1},\quad n\ge 2.$$
Then the elements $x_n$ are linearly independent, $\|x_n\|=1,$  $\|x_n-x_m\|^2=2$ for $n>m\ge 2.$  Moreover
$$\|x_2-x_1\|^2=\left (1-{1\over \sqrt{2}}\right )^2+\sum_{k=2}^\infty{1\over k(k+1)}\ge {1\over 2},$$
$$\|x_n-x_1\|^2={1\over 2}+\sum_{k\ge 2,\ k\neq n}{1\over k(k+1)}\ge {1\over 2},\qquad n\ge 3$$ We have
$$\sum_{k=2}^n{1\over \sqrt{(k-1)k}}x_k=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{1\over \sqrt{k(k+1)}}e_k \underset{n}{\longrightarrow} x_1.$$
The functional $f_1,$ if existed, would satisfy
$$0=\sum_{k=2}^n{1\over \sqrt{(k-1)k}}f_1(x_k)\underset{n}{\longrightarrow} f_1(x_1)=1$$